# как сделать пагинацию?

Tags: sql, база-данных, node.js, postgresql, запрос

Всем привет. У меня поставлена задача - сделать пагинацию. Использую node.js Postgresql
Есть таблица упражнений (просто пример) данных намного больше и даты и время разные

[image: (просто пример) данных намного больше и даты и время разные]

Не знаю как написать кверю для пагинации
Нужно чтоб  на одной страницу на сайте показывалось 3 занятия

Одно занятие это набор упражнений и повторов, например
27-11-2019 Приседания 3 подхода по 6 повторений с весом 140 кг, Жим лежа 3 подхода по 6 повторений с весом 115 кг, Жим ногами 3 подхода по 6 повторений с весом 300 кг.

Второе занятие соответсвенно похожее но дата соответственно другая и упражнения тоже.

То есть нужно стр. №1 - 3 упражнения с повторами весом, стр. №2 - 3 упражнения с повторами весом и тд.

Comment: Так по какому критерию строятся страницы: по дате или по какому-то другому?

Comment: @Ainar-G по дате (первая показанная тренировка последняю выполненная  и в низ по убываю)

Answer (score 1):

в параметрах отправляешь page= и perPage=3, тут считается оффсет на бэке

```
`SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `created_date` DESC, `id` ASC LIMIT ${perPage} OFFSET ${page*perPage}`;
```

Или limit=3, offset, считается оффсет на фронте

```
`SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `created_date` DESC, `id` ASC LIMIT ${limit} OFFSET ${offset}`;
```

Можешь поиграться с сортировкой в зависимости от того, как тебе нужно выдавать записи

Answer (score 1):

В общем, кому интересно... Я добавил таблицу trainings  в которой сохраняю дату тренировки, set_id, owner_id. Sets - это та таблица которая в самом вопросе. Каждый  set  теперь имеет training_id и теперь можно вытянуть по три тренировки на каждую страницу сайта и все sets  к каждой тренировке.

```js
WITH tr AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM trainings
    WHERE owner_id = 1 
    GROUP BY created_date, id 
    ORDER BY created_date DESC 
    LIMIT 3 OFFSET ((page - 1) * 3)
)
SELECT sets.id, sets.reps, sets.weight, sets.exercise_name, sets.training_id, sets.created_date 
FROM sets
INNER JOIN tr ON sets.training_id = tr.id 
ORDER BY tr.created_date DESC;
```